# Equivalent norms proof

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Is the standard $L^2$ norm 
$$\|u\|^2=(u,u)$$
equivalent to a weighted $L^2$ norm
$$\|u\|^2_g =(gu,u)$$
with g>0? If so, how can one prove this?

Comment: @uniquesolution $g$ is an operator, not a constant

Comment: If $g$ is a function (that is not clear as you've written your question), then you should add an assumption on $g$, because if you take $g=\exp(x^2/2)$ for example, then $u(x)=\exp(-|x|/2)$ has a finite $L^2$ norm but not in the weighted norm.

Comment: What does $g$ stand for? A scalar? A function? A linear operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If $g \in L^{\infty}(X, \mu)$ with $\def\essinf{\mathop{\rm ess\,inf}}\essinf g > 0$, then obviously
$$ \essinf g \int_X |u|^2\, d\mu \le \int_X g|u|^2\, d\mu \le \|g\|_{\infty}\int_X |u|^2 \, d\mu $$
so the answer is yes, if on the otherhand $\essinf g = 0$, then for every $n \in \mathbf N$, there is a measurable $A_n$ with $\mu(A_n) > 0$, $g|_{A_n} \le \frac 1n$. Now let $u_n := \chi_{A_n}$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \|u_n\|^2 &= \int_{A_n}\, d\mu\\
            &= \mu(A_n)\\
  \|u_n\|_g^2 &= \int_{A_n} g\, d\mu\\
            &\le \frac 1n \mu(A_n) 
\end{align*}
So 
$$ \frac{\|u_n\|_g^2}{\|u_n\|} \le \frac 1n \to 0$$
and $\|\cdot\|_g$ and $\|\cdot\|$ are not equivalent.